# Altering source file not updating DB table SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am working on a Microsoft Integration Service project, and I have a flat source file (Product.txt) that contains some data that I am saving in a SQL Server DB when I run the project.

The data is saved successfully, but when I change some values in my source Product.txt and re-run the project, the data in the SQL server are not updated.

Is there any thing that must be done to enable the update? Thank you.

Comment: Are you truncating and reloading the table? Are you somehow trying to discern what rows changed in the file? Provide some additional details about your data flow.

Comment: To answer your question of if there is anything that must be done to enable that, code it.   There is no configuration option in SSIS or data flows that can be enabled to have it automatically check source data loading into a table to check for existing rows and update.  You have to code it, using the different tasks, tsql code, etc base on what you are specifically trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do but you haven't provided enough info. I am guessing here based on the word "changed file", to me that means update.

That generally means in your data flow you should start with source, then use a lookup based on your destination to see if your "key" exists. Change the test to redirect no match.

Map no match to your inserts. And map matches to an update SQL statement.